# WCF test data providing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I have two websites that are supplied by WCF service. WCF service provides information about databases. As we have real databases and test databases (only for development purposes), so on first site there should be only real databases and on second real and test databases. So, the question is should I put filter logic on sites (so get real+test data from service and then show only needed) or on service (supply only test data or real data depends on which site requested the data)?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest putting it in the service, adding a 'DBType' parameter, so the page development is the same (use the config files to store the DBType value sent to the service) and sending it through that way.

Doing it this way allows the service to serve multiple sites so you don't need to keep changing the service if you add other 'test' sites or 'real' sites, it just sends that data from the db requested ('test', 'live', etc..)

Another way is to use two URLS, one development URL for testing, and one URL for production use. (again, use config files so the code doesn't have to change)

Always have the service filter out the real or test data

The site should just display whats given to it.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest not mixing development and production environment.
Run separate instances of WCF services for production and development.